# Visiting posts results in 404 errors after host migration

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error, options, migration

I have migrated my WordPress blog from one host to another by way of transferring the files and exporting/importing my database, updating URL references where needed.

On my new host, I can successfully view the front-page of my blog however visiting posts results in "404 - Page not found" errors, seemingly regardless of my permalink settings.

My blog as it resides on the new host can be found at [www.erogol.com](http://www.erogol.com)

Any one know the reason?

Comment: Have you verified that the PHP `mod_rewrite` module is enabled on your new host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your inner links use the `wwww` subdomain instead of the `www` subdomain. Check your General Settings to see if you added an extra `w` in your site url.

For example:

This fails: http://wwww.erogol.com/?p=653

This succeeds: http://www.erogol.com/?p=653